# C# attribute surround method with using block

Tags: c#, attributes, aop

I want to create one or more c# Attributes that can:

- MethodOptInAttribute: Surround one method code with a using block
- ClassOptInAttribute: Surround all class methods with the same using block
- MethodOptOutAttribute: opt-out a method in a class decorated by ClassOptInAttribute.

My questions are: is this possible? if not what alternatives?
I have a big DLL and I want to introduce using blocks, and I don't want to first pollute all the methods with using statements, second take the effort to modify all methods.
Thanks,

Comment: What would the using block dispose of?

Comment: Ef Context. I am trying to use ambient context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes just add metadata, they don't allow you hook into the compiler or IDE too generate code or warnings for you. That said, you could write an fxcop rule that detected where methods decorated with your attributes aren't used as intended